Are ROS2 subscription callback arguments always pointers?
I have been looking more closely at ROS2 messages. Something I have noticed is that.

The publisher always appears to take in the message object when publishing a new message and

The subscription callback always appears to be passed a message pointer vs the message object.


Is this correct?
I have also seen them passed as a reference but there isn't any documentation.

It doesn't 'have to be' but its generally good to have it that way. If you use smart pointers for the publication and subscription, then when using manual or dynamic composition with IPC enabled, then you can directly have pointers transferred to the subscribers without going over the network layer. That can be a significant improvement in performance especially for larger or very high frequency messages.
We go over this in some detail in a paper I wrote with iRobot & Open Robotics https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=MGZmVmwAAAAJ&citation_for_view=MGZmVmwAAAAJ:KlAtU1dfN6UC

Could you explain how the ROS2 internals appear to be able to handle both types?  This isn't documented anywhere, the example page didn't give details on what form the callback function would be or its argument types.
